# Selenium java como incluir una libreria de javascript externa que necesita import para funcionar

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy usando selenium con java y estoy intentando utilizar una libreria de javascript externa.

La parte de incluir la libreria  en el html es sencilla pero no se como haceer para usar el import requerido para la libreria.

Example

```
import {functionName} from '@name/functionName'
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import

**Sintaxis**

```
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { export } from "module-name";
import { export as alias } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";
import "module-name";
```

`defaultExport`

Nombre que se referirá al export por defecto del módulo.

`module-name`

El módulo desde el que importar. Normalmente es una ruta relativa o absoluta al archivo .js que contiene el módulo, excluyendo la extensión .js. Algunos empaquetadores pueden permitir o requerir el uso de la extensión; comprueba tu entorno. Sólo se permiten Strings con comillas simples o dobles.

`name`

Nombre del objeto del módulo que se utilizará como nombre de dominio al hacer referencia a los imports.

`export, exportN`

Nombre de los exports a ser importados.

`alias, aliasN`

Nombre del objeto que recibirá la propiedad importada.